# PnP Modern Search - results differ from query builder test

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, pnp

**Goal:**

Create a search solution that only searches one specific document library.

**Steps:**

Using the latest version of this SPFx solution found here: https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search

Insert a search box and connect it to a results web part.

Create a results source that targets items in the library only:

```
{searchboxquery} 
Path:"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents" 
(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
```

The query builder test results are correct.
Enter the results source GUID in the results web part properties.

**Problem:**

The results are inconsistent and return more items than are in the library, including some correct results but also oddly many from geolocation sites that are 100% irrelevant to the search parameters. For example: tenant**gbr**.sharepoint.com....., tenant**eu**.sharepoint.com.............

By the way, in the classic site this library was migrated from, content search web parts configured the same way worked perfectly, so pretty sure the config isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had removed the path: to the library from the query template option while troubleshooting this issue, but when I added it back, it started working correctly again. The only other thing I did was remove a space from the library name/url which I'd read may cause issues when the server crunches the incoming query.